# Removing all single letters from a textfile with SED

Tags: regex, sed, terminal

I want to remove all words with one letter from a textfile with the SED-command in Linux. For example, I have the text:

```
yes said holmes answering the look rather than the words it is
so i know all about mccarthy
the old man sank his face in his hands god help me he cried but
i would not have let the young man come to harm i give you my word
that i would have spoken out if it went against him at the assizes
i am glad to hear you say so said holmes gravely
i would have spoken now had it not been for my dear girl it would
break her heartit will break her heart when she hears that i am
arrested
```

With a regular expression, I use the SED-command like this:

```
sed -E 's/(\s[a-z]\s)/ /g' examplefile > destinationfile
```

After I run the command, the result looks similar like before and nothing changed. What do I miss?

Comment: Well, you only remove one letter words, so the output will be similar, see https://ideone.com/tSMtdY. Anyway, the output is different from the input.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your fundamental problem is that your `sed` doesn't understand the Perl extension `\s`.

Another problem is that matching both spaces around "a" in "ex a b c" will "consume" them so that "b" cannot be matched. If "c" is at end of line, it doesn't have a space after it, so that won't match either.

If your `sed` supports the word boundary `\b`, try that. It matches an empty string but only in positions where there is an alphabetic character only on one side of it.

```
sed 's/\b[a-z]\b//g'
```

This will leave two spaces where a removed word was surrounded by a space on both sides; there are various ways to fix that, but it's not clear from your requirements if this is necessary at all.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/(^|\s)[a-z](\s|$)/\1/Ig;ta' file
```

Remove any single char either at the start of a line, mid line or end of line, and replace it by the space (or lack of one) before it.

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/VsQNjj/1

Use `\b` instead of `\s`.

`\s` matches whitespaces. `\b` matches word boundaries.